# How to solve for f(1) in this function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, quadratics

Give that $f(x) = −4x^2 + x − 36$ for some real number $b$, part of which is graphed in the figure. What is the value of $f(1)$?

[image]

By plugging in $1$ for $x$ I come up with an expression: $-4 + b - 36$

What should be my next step for solving this problem?

Comment: please see the function graph in here. https://ibb.co/jTNbPc

Comment: Observe that the parabola touches the $X$-axis. Therefore, the trinomial must be a perfect square.

Comment: you must use that $$f(-3)=0$$

Answer (score 2):

Since $-3$ is a repeated root (from graph) of the quadratic $-4x^2+bx-36$, we have:

$$-4x^2+bx-36 = -4(x+3)^2$$

Comparison gives us $b=-24$.

Comment: how did you get -3 from the function?

Comment: @Hayk Because it is zero at that point? from the graph.

Answer (score 0):

From the graph it is clear that $\ f(x)$ has repeated root at $\ x = -3$ because at that point the quadratic touches x - axis .

So , $\ f'(x) = -8x + b$ , also has a root at $\ x = -3$ . Which implies $\ b =  -24$ .

So , $\ f(x) = -4x^2-24x-36$ . And hence $\ f(1) = -64$.